# Python code has the following import

Tags: python

I cannot figure out what this import does and how to use it in the python code. I am new to python.

```
import datasources.google as google
```

Comment: Why not search "python import as"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code imports the module `datasources.google`. When you import a whole module with `import whatevermodule`, you have to include it every time you use a thing from that module, like so:

```
datasources.google.dowhatever(thing)
```

Since `datasources.google` is really long, it would be nice to have a short way of writing it.  That's what the `as google` part does. It means you can instead write:

```
google.dowhatever(thing)
```

and saves you a bunch of typing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing datasources.google.method, you can now write google.method, see [PEP221](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221) for more details...